# "Read only" error in assigning driver function to netdev_ops function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm experimenting with network drivers in a qemu VM running Ubuntu 16.04.1. `uname -r` gives 4.4.0-31-generic as the kernel version.

In [linux/netdevice.h for that kernel version](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/netdevice.h?v=4.4), I found the comment

"@netdev_ops:    Includes several pointers to callbacks,
                  if one wants to override the ndo_*() functions"

However, in my code, an assignment such as `dev->netdev_ops->ndo_open = netmod_open` (where netmod_open is the open method in my own driver) gives the compiler error:

`assignment of member 'ndo_open' in read-only object`

Further, `netdev_ops` is declared as `const` in the source:

```
const struct net_device_ops *netdev_ops;
```

How can I "override the ndo_*() functions" if the struct containing their pointers is `const`?

Comment: It looks like I need to create my own `struct net_device_ops` and then assign `dev->netdev_ops` the address of that `struct`. So in general I need to learn more about how data structures are passed around in the kernel. Any links to such info would be appreciated. It seems like most of the tutorials I find have outdated kernel APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I "override the ndo_*() functions"

Define your own variable of type `struct net_device_ops`, setup its fields(hooks actually) which you want to override, and assign this variable to `dev->netdev_ops`.

Note, that according to [description](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/netdevice.h?v=4.4#L780) for `struct net_device_ops`, the only field `.ndo_start_xmit` is required to be set, other fields you may leave non-initialized (that is NULL).